# MapInfo Pro 12.5 Pan Control not going upward when measuring a distance

Tags: mapinfo

MapInfo Pro 12.5  (32 bit)
In one workspace I am measuring a distance - I can pan left right and down, but not upwards.
The pan works in another workspace in all directions.
Why does it not work in the workspace? 
Is there a particular setting in the Map Preferences or Map Options that needs to be selected to enable the pan to work in all directions.....?

Below is an image of Map Options
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the "Autoscroll" option that controls whether the map pans if you move the cursor "outside" the window while drawing or measuring.

You do however seem to have "Autoscroll" enabled.

Another thing that can prevent it, is if the border of your map window is outside the application area of MapInfo Pro, as you see here:
[image]

You can fix that by scrolling the map window back into the application area.

Comment: Thank you Peter - yes very simple in the end. The Autoscroll panning works in each direction as long as the window is at the extent of the application. Thanks again - it works well now!