# QGIS Autoscroll map option?

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS and still exploring the basics.
I want to drag my polygon beyond the window of the map. In Mapinfo they have the autoscroll option , so if the region of the map is outside the current view, the map will automatically move upward/ downward with the mouse direction.

How can I accomplish the same thing in QGIS?

[MapInfo Pro 12.5 Pan Control not going upward when measuring a distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197338/mapinfo-pro-12-5-pan-control-not-going-upward-when-measuring-a-distance)